# API endpoint works in browser but not with GET

Tags: r, get, endpoint

I'm trying to make a request to an API using the GET function in **R**. The link I use works in my browser but not in GET stating it needed a valid key for the request. I noticed that if I wasn't logged in on the browser the request would also fail. At this point I'm not sure how to make the call using GET.

This is basically the call I was making where `data$name1[i]` would be for example A6156

```
base="https://legislation.nysenate.gov"
searchbill=paste("/api/3/bills/search?term=",data$name1[i],sep="")
searchresult=GET(paste(base,searchbill,"//?key=",key,sep=""))
```

I've tried messing with the url but I still get a 401 error on the request. In my browser after clearing out my cookies and logging out from https://legislation.nysenate.gov/bills/search, the request no longer worked until I logged back in.

Comment: update: i was able to get it working by setting the cookies using the values from my browser. however it did work once prior to setting the cookies. now im curious why it was able to work prior to setting the cookies

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have obtained an API key, which you have assigned to variable `key` in your code. If that is the case, I believe you can make your code work by adjusting the syntax:

```
base="https://legislation.nysenate.gov"
searchbill=paste("/api/3/bills/search?term=",data$name1[i],sep="")
searchresult=GET(paste(base,searchbill,"&key=",key,sep=""))
```